# Recreating core data at application launch

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have an app that connects to a website. I store its data as core data and then I use the core data to load my tableviews. I believe, I want to reload the data from the website every time I launch the app, since the user could change the data if they were to go onto the website.

What's the best way to approach this? Should I just delete the core data each time the app terminates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how critical it is that data on the device always be current, on how long you expect users to wait before working with the app, and on what you want to happen if someone tries to use the app when the network is slow or unavailable. If you delete the store, and the app can't connect immediately, the user has no data. Even if the network is fine, the user still has to wait on network and server latency before they can start using the app. This is likely to be poor UX.

On the other hand if you allow data to persist after the app exits, the user's data might not be current, at least not at first.

If you don't ever want the data to persist after the app exits, an in-memory store might be the best choice, because it will never be saved to a file anyway.

If presenting potentially old data is OK either (a) briefly when the app starts up or (b) when the network is unavailable, a better choice would be to keep the data store but make new network calls to update the existing data. You could provide some sort of UI to indicate that updates are in progress. You might also have some in-app indication of when your app last synced with the server.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I really should keep the data but then provide some sort of indication that it might not be current, when it was last updated or that updates are in progress like you suggested. I like that idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load all the data in memory (and also want to do updates) then you can create a managed object context backed by a `NSAtomicStore` persistent store subclass. In the NSAtomicStore subclass you can implement the read: (`load:` method) and the CRUD actions (`newReferenceObjectForManagedObject:`, `save`: and `updateCacheNode:fromManagedObject:` methods)

Comment: I read a few things on NSAtomicStore but I still don't know why you'd want to use it. None of the articles or Apple's documentation are really clear on the why. Plus, it seems like too much overhead for just wanting to delete the data and then load up new data. Maybe I'm just still ignorant to its ways.

Comment: NSAtomicStore is for creating custom persistent store formats. It lets you go beyond the Apple supplied xml, binary, in-memory and sqlite stores. It's overkill for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of how your application makes use of the Core Data stack, but if you don't care about (or don't have) changes made locally on the device, I'd say the easiest way to refresh the data from the server is just what you said: wipe out the store file, re-create it and import the data from the server. However, I wouldn't do this systematically on each application launch. Make sure the user knows about it and think of providing a "refresh" button to trigger that procedure. Also make sure you *can* download new content from the server, before wiping out the local store.